# PostgreSQL deadlock between select for update even ordering

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, postgresql-9.2, database-deadlocks

I have two query that deadlock together

```
PERFORM id
FROM stack
WHERE id IN (SELECT tmp.stkid FROM tmp_push_bulk tmp WHERE tmp.stkid > 0)
ORDER BY id
FOR UPDATE OF stack
```

And

```
PERFORM stk.id
FROM stack stk
WHERE stk.referer IN (
      SELECT tmp.id
      FROM tmp_renew_stk tmp
)
ORDER BY stk.id
FOR UPDATE OF stk
```

The error is:

```
- PG (20:46:37) [14786]: Execute command failed: ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 14797 waits for ShareLock on transaction 183495696; blocked by process 24303.
Process 24303 waits for ShareLock on transaction 183495704; blocked by process 14797.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

I also think that every process lock its row in ordering of id column, so deadlock is impossible. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the `IN` expression locks rows in unspecific order (untested). I would generally replace `IN` on bigger sets with a `JOIN` where possible. This is faster to begin with, thereby minimizing the chance for deadlocks. I would try:

Update: According to your comment you have many duplicates. Assuming dupes in the temp table I suggest a subquery for three purposes:

- Fold duplicates.
- Using `DISTINCT` it's particularly cheap to sort rows in the subquery at the same.
- Apply `WHERE` conditon `AND tmp.stkid > 0`

```
PERFORM s.id
FROM  stack s
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT stkid
   FROM   tmp_push_bulk
   WHERE  stkid > 0
   ) tmp ON tmp.stkid = s.id 
ORDER BY 1
FOR   UPDATE OF s;
```

And:

```
PERFORM s.id
FROM  stack s
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT id
   FROM   tmp_renew_stk
   ) tmp ON tmp.id = s.referer
ORDER BY 1
FOR   UPDATE OF s;
```

Comment: Hmm, because there is many duplicated rows, so I use IN condition to remove its automatically. From PostgreSQL documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE): It is possible for a SELECT command using ORDER BY and FOR UPDATE/SHARE to return rows out of order. This is because ORDER BY is applied first.

Comment: @TruongHua: Are the duplicates in the temp tables or in table `stack`? What you found about `ORDER BY` *might* be related to your deadlocks, if two instances try to lock rows in the same order, but one of them sees different values for some rows after an UPDATE in another concurrent transaction and therefore orders differently. A pretty unlikely scenario though. If you have duplicates in table `stack` there is a more likely explanation: the order is not well defined for duplicates! You could solve this by adding more expressions to `ORDER BY` to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Duplicates only in tmp table